# how to show a message box with ok and cancel button

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7.1

I am building an app for windows phone 7 where i need to show a message box with both ok and cancel button. When ok button is pressed i want to navigate to a new page while when cancel button is pressed i want to stay in the same page:

The code which i wrote is:

```
 public Donate()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        MessageBoxResult result =
            MessageBox.Show("This Will Take You Out Of The App And Forward You To Our Contribution Website!",
            "", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);

        if (result == MessageBoxResult.OK)
        {
            donation.Source = new Uri("http://mobiledonation.vzons.com/ArvindKejriwal", UriKind.Absolute);

            donation.Loaded += (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) =>
            {
                donation.Navigate(new Uri("http://mobiledonation.vzons.com/ArvindKejriwal", UriKind.Absolute));
            };
        }

        else
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/AAP.xaml", UriKind.Relative));


    }
```

Now here the problem is that when cancel button is pressed i get a Null reference exception in the statement

NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/AAP.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

Ok button is working fine but when cancel button is pressed i want to stay in the same page i.e AAP.xaml. How can i achieve this?

Comment: Just comment this line in else part  NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/AAP.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

Comment: @Praveen ya i did that but it doesnot work. I just want to dismiss the mesaage box when cancel is pressed and stay in the same page

Comment: I have run your code by commenting the else part and it is working fine. It is on same page when cancel is pressed.

Comment: @Praveen I was in the AAP.xaml page where i had a button which when clicked the messagebox is displayed. Now when ok is pressed i am navigated to the page but when cancel is pressed i get a white screen.

Comment: Messagbox has default feature that on cancel button is pressed it remains on same page.. You need to check your code on page for white screen . it is not the cancel button issue.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46898/discussion-between-user3156298-and-praveen)